# Split CSV file using standard csv.reader method

Tags: python, csv

For example, my CSV file contains 4 lines:

```
CREATE TABLE test(col_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, col_name_2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0
 NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE test2(col_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, col_name_2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0
 NOT NULL);
```

I'd like to split it by ";" in order to have 2 elements in the list. Can I do that using the standard csv.reader method? I know that I can use the Pandas.read_csv method.

My current code:

```
with open("my_file.csv", newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

Comment: The problem is that as you mentioned, they are 4 lines, when they are read they would be four rows. To have to list you desire, you should concatinated every two rows. which is something you do while reading the rows.

Comment: @alphaBetaGamma 
I'm wondering can I implement something like that using the csv.reader:
data = csvfile.read().split(";")

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
with open("my_file.csv", "r", newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
    lines = csvfile.read().strip().rstrip(";").replace("\n", "").split(";")
```

Result:

```
['CREATE TABLE test(col_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, col_name_2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL)',
 'CREATE TABLE test2(col_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, col_name_2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL)']
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this solves your problem because the split ';' works for fields but not in your case.

```
import csv
with open("file.csv",encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
count = 1
rows = []
for row in reader:
    if count % 2 == 0 :
        row1.append(" ".join(row))
        rows.append(" ".join(row1))
        row1 = []
    else:
        row1 = row
    count = count + 1
print(rows)
```

output:
[image]